# Why doesn't MAHLI get to be in Curiosity selfies?

Tags: photography, curiosity, mahli

**note:** Answer(s) to [Why is a corner of InSight's selfie cropped like this?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32800/12102) don't address this question about Curiosity for several reasons:

1. It doesn't even *answer that question properly.*
2. Insight is not a rover and *does not have anywhere near the same number of additional cameras* as does Curiosity.
3. Insight does not produce nearly as many photos per camera as does Curiosity, because (did I mention) Insight is not a rover, and so there is less public activity analyzing, composing montaging and otherwise working with it's images as there is for Curiosity's large body of photographic work.
4. I can't prove it but I'll bet there has been fewer full selfies initiated by Insight than by Curiosity.

---

The new NASA video [How NASA's Mars Curiosity Rover Takes a Selfie](https://youtu.be/L_ii2GABPao) answers the question I always wanted to ask; *How (the heck) does Curiosity take its selfie?*

The video shows the rover's robotic arm move MAHLI (the [Mars Hand Lens Imager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Hand_Lens_Imager)) through a wide range of positions and directions.

*Presumably* the video shows this because there's another camera on the rover imaging the robotic arm.

And yet the robotic arm is missing from the final image.

**Question:** Why is this part of the rover therefore still missing from most selfies? Has this been discussed in authoritative sources? Have attempts been made to include it, at least in black-and-white?

GIF from screen shots from the linked video *demonstrates the wide range of motion and orientation* of the robotic arm as seen from another camera on Curiosity.

[image: Curiosity's MAHLI GIF from How NASA's Mars Curiosity Rover Takes a Selfie]

---

From [***Seventeen Cameras*** *on* Curiosity](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/msl/multimedia/malin-4.html)**:

[image: NASA: Seventeen Cameras on Curiosity]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a corner of InSight's selfie cropped like this?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32800/why-is-a-corner-of-insights-selfie-cropped-like-this)

Comment: for the same reason you don't see your hand when you take a selfie

Comment: @JCRM quipy but wrong. Read the question *in toto* and give it some more thought. I you'd like to post a proper answer where voting is possible that would be great!

Comment: @JCRM while related, your proposed dupe does not really answer the question as I have written it. I invite you to have another look at it and then reconsider, thanks!

Comment: @uhoh - have you read this: http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2015/08191059-curiosity-self-portrait-history-belly-pan.html

Comment: @uhoh Wait. I'm still having trouble understanding your question. Are you asking why the MAHLI arm doesn't get to be in Curiosity's selfies?

Comment: @StarMan Is that substantially different from ***Question:*** *Why is this part (the robotic arm) of the rover therefore still missing from most selfies? Has this been discussed in authoritative sources? Have attempts been made to include it, at least in black-and-white?* My feeling is that one *could be made* that includes the robotic arm, though it may likely be (at least partially) in black and white. Also see the conversation below [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/42051/12102).

Comment: So you have to merge images which have totally different point of views. Is that even possible ?  Unless maybe if you would rotate Curiosity 180 $⁰$ at the same spot.

Answer (score 6):

It's two reasons actually. Since the MAHLI has a narrow FOV, it can't fit the entire rover in one photograph. Similar to the reason why you don't see your arm when you take a selfie. The camera's FOV isn't big enough to fit your arm (unless you point the camera down, then your arm will be visible). However, this is only the case when the MAHLI images the upper part of the rover. The arm should be visible when photographing the wheels, the bottom of the rover, and etc, right? The second reason is that NASA crops the arm out of the individual photos and merges it with another photo. Here's a visual example of this:
[image]

This was image was originally from [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Curiosity-Mars-Rover-take-pictures-of-itself).
Here is NASA's explanation from [this source](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/msl/news/msl20121211b.html):

> MAHLI is mounted on a turret at the end of Curiosity's robotic arm. The arm is not visible in the portrait because the arm was positioned out of the shot in the images or portions of images used in the mosaic. Some images taken during the day show portions of the arm. However, the Martian ground that the arm hides from view in those images is visible in alternative images chosen for the mosaic, taking the arm out of the scene.

Comment: I show and refer to *images of MAHLI* and its arm from a wide range of perspectives and mention attempts in black-and-white is to drive the point home that Curiosity has a large number of cameras. This answer only addresses *images by MAHLI*. So your "two reasons" about the MAHLI camera don't really address my question. If I had asked "Why aren't there any photos of the photographer?" The answer is not "Because they didn't bring a selfie stick" because all of the other people in the photos had phones with cameras. They could have photographed the photographer.

Comment: @uhoh - The MastCams and HazCams are not suitable for a self-photo -- they are more like a helmet mounted GoPro.  MAHLI is the only *handheld* camera available, so it's the only way to take a selfie (without a mirror or a detachable camera or another lander nearby).

Comment: @amI I have a reasonable understanding of how cameras work. Why suppose that one must choose only one camera for a *profoundly composite image?* My question asks about *attempts in black and white* so starting with a MAHLI set and then adding to them more images just for example like those I show in the question could work. You'd have do more of the same creative cropping to make the background work is all.

Comment: @uhoh - what good is a picture of your arm taken from your shoulder if you want your arm to appear in a composite selfie?

Comment: @amI that's not a good analogy because [the arm has five degrees of freedom of movement provided by rotary actuators known as the shoulder azimuth joint, shoulder elevation joint, elbow joint, wrist joint and turret joint.](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/msl/multimedia/pia16144.html) The five images in the GIF *from just one of Curiosity's many cameras* were selected to show some of that range of motion, as pointed out in the question.

Comment: @uhoh - perhaps you could sketch the scene that you desire -- then imagine what camera takes a picture of the arm so that it's in the same scene as the chassis (without looking like a Picasso painting).

Comment: @amI that's already addressed by [You'd have do more of the same creative cropping to make the background work is all.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/42025/why-doesnt-mahli-get-to-be-in-curiosity-selfies/42051?noredirect=1#comment137569_42051) though it may be slightly more edge-intensive. Since constructing complete and "attractive" selfies from image ensembles has probably crossed from science, engineering and mission management at least partially into the world of art, I'm all for seeing the first Mars-themed and Mars-sourced cubist collage! If I were rich I'd commission one!

Comment: @amI I've added another image to the question. I have a hunch that nearly every bit of the robot's arm can be photographed by either one of the other cameras on the rover or by MAHLI itself.

Comment: @StarMan ditto. Also I've just asked [How will Mars 2020 rover Perseverance's selfie skills compare to Curiosity's? Will it have any additional selfie-related capabilities?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/42091/12102)