# How will Perseverance's selfie skills compare to Curiosity's? Will it have any additional selfie-related capabilities?

Tags: nasa, mission-design, rovers, perseverance, photography

The design of the Mars 2020 rover [Perseverance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseverance_(rover)) benefits from years of operational experience with Curiosity. While 2020's instrument suite differs in several ways it looks remarkably similar to Curiosity, at least to the untrained eye.

In terms of potential selfie *capabilities* (and not just what the first ones will look like), will anything be different?

---

From Space.com's [2020 Vision: NASA's Next Mars Rover Will Have Nearly Two Dozen Cameras](https://www.space.com/38645-nasa-2020-mars-rover-23-cameras.html):

[image: A selection of the 23 cameras on NASA's 2020 Mars rover]

> A selection of the 23 cameras on NASA's 2020 Mars rover. Many are improved versions of the cameras on the Curiosity rover, with a few new additions as well. (Image credit: NASA/JPL-Caltech)

Comment: different but related: [Why doesn't MAHLI get to be in Curiosity selfies?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/42025/12102)

Comment: The good news is the hazcams are colour, so pictures of the arm won't be in black and white

Comment: Why worry about taking selfies when you can have a flying camera around you ?

Comment: @Cornelisinspace That sounds like an excellent "Yes it will" answer!

Comment: @Cornelisinspace here's your source, go for it!  https://youtu.be/GhsZUZmJvaM?t=779

Comment: But that wouldn't be a real selfie, in the end the helicopter is not a physical part of Perseverance. !

Comment: @Cornelisinspace oh I see what you mean. Yes they said "mutual selfie" but I guess the idea is that each would take a photo of the other, or I suppose  Perseverance could take a photo of both of them together, but that just brings us back to where we started.

Comment: @Cornelis I think you can write that up at least a supplementary answer now https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/25862/ingenuity-spots-perseverance-from-the-air/

Comment: That's a very cool picture ! What a shame we have to leave Ingenuity behind.. :(